# how do I add the license directory key to mplab xc32?

Tags: pic32

I have gone through the steps and ran all the license things on my computer, but it still says I need to register for a free c++ compiler

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<xclm>
    <xclm:Activation xclm:url="http://keygen.microchip.com" />
    <xclm:Demo xclm:url="http://www.microchip.com/xcdemo/handler.aspx" /> 
  <xclm:LicenseDirectory xclm:path="C:\ProgramData\Microchip\xclm\license" />
</xclm>
```

That's what `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microchip\xc32\v1.31\etc\xclm.conf`  should have.  Just make sure you went through and installed the license from http://www.microchip.com/xcdemo/xcpluspromo.aspx

On mine, I installed it, but had to add the `LicenseDirectory` key myself, and took me a while to find the name of that key, so here it is.